# I can't make a list of user and the places that they can't go if they have been there in the last 6 months

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PSQL so I am sorry if it's a silly mistake, but I am having the following problem.
I am trying to make a list that show the user and the places that they haven't gone to in at least 6 months.
Here is the code that I am using:

```
SELECT pk_user_id,pk_place_id,
    AGE('2023-05-26',date) AS test
    FROM visit
    WHERE test > 6;
```

I also tried this one:

```
SELECT pk_user_id,pk_place_id,
    AGE('2023-05-26',date) AS test
    FROM visit
    HAVING test > 6;
```

And here is the code for the table:

```
CREATE SCHEMA code

CREATE TABLE code.place ( 
   pk_place_id VARCHAR(8), 
   place_name VARCHAR (50),
   CONSTRAINT pk_place_id PRIMARY KEY (pk_place_id)
);


CREATE TABLE code.user ( 
   pk_user_id VARCHAR(3), 
   user_name VARCHAR (50),
   CONSTRAINT pk_user_id PRIMARY KEY (pk_user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE code.visit ( 
   pk_user_id VARCHAR(3), 
   pk_place_id VARCHAR(8),
   data DATE,
   CONSTRAINT pk_user_id FOREIGN KEY (pk_user_id) REFERENCES code.user,
   CONSTRAINT pk_place_id FOREIGN KEY (pk_place_id) REFERENCES code.place
);
```

The problem is that when I use this code it says that the column test doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `WHERE` clause or on `HAVING` clause you cannot use alias of fields. For using aliases on `WHERE` clause or on `HAVING` clause you must use subquery.
**And not recommended using having without group by.**
So, correct syntax:

```
SELECT pk_user_id,pk_place_id,
AGE('2023-05-26',date) AS test
FROM visit
WHERE AGE('2023-05-26',date) > 6;
```

or

```
select * from (     
    SELECT pk_user_id, pk_place_id,
    AGE('2023-05-26',date) AS test
    FROM visit
) tb 
WHERE tb.test > 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ramin. I would like to thank you for your answer, I also manage to solve it using the following method:

```
SELECT pk_place_id, pk_user_id, date
FROM visita
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM age(NOW(),date))*12 + EXTRACT(month FROM age(now(),date)) > 6;
```